# Python Syntax Error or Bug?

Tags: python, syntax, if-statement

I've just begun learning Python and I'm using the IDLE ide to learn programming.
I've been trying a basic code I saw on the official site but it keeps saying 'Incorrect Syntax' and highlights the keyword 'else' here's the program:

```
a=40
if a <= 40:
    print("True")
    else:
```

The 'else' is highlighted and I'm told it's a syntax error.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In Python, Whitespace is part of the syntax. The syntax error lies in your usage of whitespace.

Comment: Pro tip: When learning a new language or library, or anything, if you get a syntax error you can assume you did something wrong. 99.99% of the time it is *not* a bug.

Comment: @Volatility: Which only illustrates all the more why the OP doesn't understand what is wrong. I indented it to match the original error image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `else` block needs to be indented at the same level as the `if` block.

```
if a <= 40:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your identation for the `else:` clause (even when working on the console). The alignment of `else:` has to agree with that of the `if`